# Pointers in C. Why isn't my two-dimensional array printed?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to use this code in a more complex problem, but I didn't get it to work. Why isn't my matrix getting printed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_mat(int **a, int n)
{
    printf("\n");
    int k,t;
    for (k=1;k<=n;k++)
    {
        for (t=1;t<=n;t++)
            printf("%d ", a[k][t]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,n,**a;
    printf("Chess board size=");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a=(int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        a[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
            a[i][j]=-1;
    print_mat(a,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your actual output? If, e.g. "segmentation fault", that's something you should tell us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should first malloc for size of `int *` not `int` , change

```
a = ( int ** )malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );
```

to

```
a = malloc( n * sizeof( int* ) ); //also no need to cast.
```

Also, as @Russell Borogove suggested, change loop as `for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )` instead of from `1 to n`.

Comment: Rather `a = malloc(n * sizeof(*a));`, but +1 for "no need to cast".

Comment: What about int (*a)[n]= malloc(n*sizeof(int[n])) ?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, I don't get what are you referring to.

Comment: To allocate dinamically a pointer to array, so all the memory is adjacent and can use functions like memset to write on that memory that is an unique block.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, in that case you can do `a = malloc(n*n*sizeof(int))`.

Comment: The size is the same, but the significant thing is that a is int (*a)[n] and not int **, so all the memory is adjacent.If I say int* a=malloc(n*n*sizeof(int)) , then I must access all the elements without double indexes, having int (*a)[n] allows to use the double indexing and to have all the memory adjacent.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri But if you pass an `int (*)[n]` to a function expecting an `int **`, nasty surprises are likely.

Comment: A good compiler always gives a warning if someone tries to do this. I never had problems, provide an example.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to get in the habit of using zero-based indexes with C arrays, and display them as if they were 1-based only when presenting things to users.

Change your `for (i=1;i<=n;i++)` loops to `for (i=0;i<n;i++)`. Likewise with `j`, `k`, and `t`.

As currently written, `a[n]` isn't an allocated pointer, and `a[0][n]` isn't within the `a[0]` buffer allocation. The result (gcc 4.2.1 on OSX 10.7.5) is a program crash.

Comment: I know that, but for this particular problem it was more efficient to start from one instead of zero.

Comment: It's not "more efficient", just more familiar. In this case, it's also *wrong* - a[n] isn't an allocated pointer, and a[0][n] is off the end of the a[0] buffer allocation. Get in the habit of using 0 based indexes in C, and display them as 1-based only in user-facing display. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

`a=(int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int));`

change to `a= mallo(n*sizeof(int*))`

On some systems `int` and `int*` (pointers) can have same size but here may be this is creating the problem.

Also

```
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
     a[i][j]=-1;
```

change it to

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    a[i][j]=-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
a=(int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

should read

```
a=malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
```